# How can I modify NSPredicate to ignore whitespaces in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I am filtering a `CNContact` `phoneNumbers` to see if dialed number is contained within the `contact's` number. Bellow attached code works fine, but.....

**My problem: If the phone number has no white spaces inside, works ok but if I search "0761" and contact's phone number is "076 1", it ignores it.**

I am using `NSPredicate`. Code:

```
func filterAndGetCurrentPhoneNumber(c: CNContact) -> String{
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.value.stringValue CONTAINS[c] %@", self.txtf_dial.text!)    
        let array = (c.phoneNumbers as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        if array.count > 0{
            let str: String? = ((array[0] as! CNLabeledValue).value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            if str != nil {
                return str!;
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
```

**How can I modify `NSPredicate` to ignore whitespaces in swift?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPredicate that ignores whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088688/nspredicate-that-ignores-whitespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPredicate` has no such search option, so you'd need to perform the filtering yourself. Instead of going to `predicateWithBlock:`, though, you might as well stick to the Swift standard library.

```
// an extension to make the string processing calls shorter
extension String {
    func numericString() -> String {
        // split and rejoin to filter out the non-numeric chars
        let set = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
        return self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(set).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
}

// your function
func filteredPhone(c: CNContact, filterText: String) -> String {
    // conform the query string to the same character set as the way we want to search target strings
    let query = filterText.numericString()

    // filter the phone numbers
    let filtered = c.phoneNumbers.filter({ val in
        let phone = (val.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
        // conform the target string to numeric characters only
        let conformed = phone.numericString()
        return conformed.containsString(query)
    })
    if let result = filtered.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
        return result.stringValue
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

// test case
let contact = CNMutableContact()
contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "867-5309"))]
filteredPhone(contact, filterText: "753")
```

By the way... I left the interface to your function largely unchanged. But unless it's important to use the empty string as this function's result in the UI, it's generally better to use an Optional return value to indicate a lack of search result — that way code that calls this function can tell the difference between a search that returns no result and a search whose result is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use trimmingCharacters()

  trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and
  end of a string.

  For exemple : "hello" == " hello " == "hello " == " hello"

"hello world" == " hello world " == "hello world " == " hello world"

string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the OP specifically asked how to ignore whitespace within the phone number string, not just at the start and end.  
Rickster's accepted answer shows how to do this in the numericString extension.