# NSPredicate: filtering objects using free text against an NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data model with an NSDate property. I want to filter the database by typing in any text such as a month and/or a year e.g. "May", "2001", "May 2001"  etc. The 1st example would bring back any objects where the month of the data is May, the 2nd would bring back objects for the year 2001, the 3rd would bring back objects for May 2001.

I assume the solution will involve an NSPredicate, but I'm not sure how to put it all together.

Can I format the NSDate property somehow and simply do a [contains] searchtext?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By free text ,does it include day also?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *yesterday = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0];
NSDate *thisWeek  = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0];
NSDate *lastWeek  = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -1209600.0];

NSArray *dates = @[today, yesterday, thisWeek, lastWeek];

NSArray *filteredArray = [dates filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
 [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDate *item, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    // Logic for searching comes here
    // For instance date with day 27 
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:item];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    return (day == 27);

}]];

NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It pointed me in the right direction - much appreciated!

Comment: ok, so this didnt work because it appears NSPredicate with block is not supported in Core Data

Comment: NSPredicate is a class in Foundation.framework. What do u mean by not supported in core data. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but using it in a fetch request throws an exception. I am having the same issues as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543208/nsfetchrequest-and-predicatewithblock as I am using SQlLite

Answer (score 0):

You could always get the date as string using `NSDateFormatter` (or simple `description` method) and do a check for particular string. But for this you will have to get all objects from your store which will be very inefficient.
 Instead you could create another relationship (or custom attribute) to a `Date` entity which will have day, month and year information. (You can have this along with the date attribute or without it). Then it will be easy to write predicates whatever may be the type of search you are trying to perform - month, date or day.

And for setting and getting the attribute you could use custom methods in the `NSManagedObject` subclass for the entity.

For eg: if your entity is `Event` which looks like

**Event**

- **eName**
- **eDate**   (Another Entity **EventDate**- one to one relationship)

and `EventDate` looks like

**EventDate**

- **day**
- **month**
- **year**

then for setting using date

```
-(void)setEDateUsingDate:(NSDate *)date{
//gather current calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //gather date components from date
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

    //set date components
    self.eDate.day=[dateComponents day];
    self.eDate.month=[dateComponents month];
    self.eDate.year=[dateComponents year];
}
```

and getting the date would be

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromEDate{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   [components setDay:self.eDate.day];
   [components setMonth:self.eDate.month];
   [components setMonth:self.eDate.year];
   NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
   return date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks or your suggestion. I would prefer not to have to create another attribute at these stage but may have to go that route if I don't find a better method.