# Large array of NSManagedObjects

Tags: core-data, memory-management, nsarray, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectid

Application have viewcontroller with large array of objects and it has a serious memory pressure. There are a solution - store only managedObjectIds array instead of managed objects, but I'm not sure that is a most efficient way to optimize memory management because object ids is are long too. Is there any solution to reduce memory usage?

Comment: Do you use a table view or a collection view to show objects?

Comment: Yes, I use table view to present these objects

Comment: Do you use also use the `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: No, just fetching objects and sorting with blocks, where sorting is related to object's childs(childs is fetching with predicates). Because of complex filtering and sorting I use custom object(not managed object) as parent of managed object. Sorry, I forgot to mention this important detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of complex filtering and sorting I use custom object(not
>   managed object) as parent of managed object. Sorry, I forgot to
>   mention this important detail

You should try to move filtering and sorting to be a `predicate` and `sortDescriptors` of `NSFetchRequest`. Then you could use `fetchBatchSize` to limit the number of objects which are simultaneously fetched from the persistent store and kept in memory.

Comment: Is it applicable for CoreData to use predicates and sort descriptors with blocks instead of string descriptions?

Comment: @user578205: it's not possible. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543208/nsfetchrequest-and-predicatewithblock) an explanation. You'll have to change them, such that they can be translated into SQL queries.